# Select value of jsonb column in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a table 'Documents' which has a column 'Tags' with 'jsonb' datatype. 
Sample data in Tags column

```
 [{"Tag": "Social Media"}, {"Tag": "Adobe Creative"}]
 [{"Tag": "Interactive"}]
 [{"Tag": "Web 2.0"}, {"Tag": "Adobe Creative"},{"Tag": "Suite"}]
```

I need to get the distinct values of "Tag" like

```
 Social Media 
 Adobe Creative
 Interactive
 Web 2.0
 Suite
```

I am new in PostgreSQL.

Comment: This might help you. 

http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/102556/is-it-possible-to-select-distinct-values-in-a-json-document-using-postgresql

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The shortest version would be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT value->'Tag' AS tag
FROM Documents, jsonb_array_elements(Documents.Tags);
```

The [`jsonb_array_elements()` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) unnests the JSONB array into a set of rows with a single column called "value". It uses an implicit "lateral join" on the `Documents` table.

This gives you the distinct tags as `jsonb` values. If you want them as a `text` value, use the `->>` operator instead of `->`.

Comment: If I need to add a where condition with this jsonb data type ,what shall I do? Eg. select * from documents where tags->'Tag' = 'Suite'

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, then the answer is no, because you can not directly access computed field values in the select list as filter conditions. You would either need to repeat the function calls or - probably easier in your case - use the above as a sub-query and then filter in the main query. In either case, you should use the `->>` operator to get the text version of the JSON object.

Comment: SELECT *
FROM documents,   jsonb_array_elements(
  documents.tags
  ) AS elem
WHERE elem->>'Tag' = 'Suite';     From this I got the required result. Thank you

Answer (score 10):

you can also use the following snippet.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  Tags::json->'Tag'
FROM Documents;
```

Answer (score 8):

## since Postgres 9.6+

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  Tags->>'Tag'
FROM Documents;
```